# Do Ward identities imply that there is an (effective) Lagrangian invariant under the symmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, renormalization, ward-identity

In usual perturbative QFT, if the UV Lagrangian is invariant under a symmetry $G$ and the regularization of the path integral does not break $G$, the Feynman rules are explicitly invariant under $G$. Therefore, under RG flow, the IR Lagrangian must also be invariant under $G$.

However, let us move away from the usual setup and suppose that $G$ is NOT a symmetry of the UV Lagrangian, but by some other method one can show that the ward identities for $G$ are true in the IR. In other words, $G$ is an emergent symmetry in the IR. Is there an abstract argument for why the effective Lagrangian in the IR must be invariant under $G$?